# How to access a Java class in the default package from jshell?

Tags: java, jshell, default-package

I am unable to access Java classes in the default package from `jshell`. I cannot import since the default package has no name and when I try to reference the name then I have an error:

> jshell> Test.test(); |  Error: |  cannot find symbol |    symbol:
>   variable Test |  Test.test(); |  ^--^

The only solution I found so far is using:

> /open Test.java

Is it possible or is it a bug?

Here the code of `Test.java`:

```
public class Test {
    public static void test() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test.test();
    }
}
```

Comment: for using `Test.test()`, did you create a `Test` class within `jshell`?

Comment: No. But the class is in the class path. If I modify the source for Test, add a package name and recompile. I can import the class in jshell and use it without problem.

Comment: That is quite possible, given that every class in Java-9 should reside within a package else the compilation fails. But not sure, why `jshell` doesn't warn you of that while the classes are added to the classpath.

Comment: I am compiling with Java 12 and I have no warning for using the default package.

Comment: Can you share the implementation of the `Test` class as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/jshell/external-code.html#GUID-D0BED087-AD44-4048-B37D-054308C64390),

> Code in the default package, which is also known as the unnamed package, can’t be accessed from JShell.